# N tosses of a coin ,what is the probability that number of heads are even?

Tags: probability

We have a coin with probability of head is p and probability for tail is (1-p).
We toss the coin N times, what is the probability that the number of tosses that show head is even?

What I've tried is to sum over all even k's (k= 0,2,4,...) and to sum up the probability that the number of heads is k. Is there a way to elinimate the sum and to give a closed formula?

Comment: certainly [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) will be of help

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle (x+y)^n + (x-y)^n = 2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{2k}x^{n-2k}y^{2k}$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks. Where can I find this formula? I didn't see it at the wiki article on the Binomial theorem

Comment: Write out the right sides of the following two equations using the binomial theorem: $$\begin{align}(x+y)^n &= x^n + nx^{n-1}y + \cdots \\(x-y)^n &= x^n - nx^{n-1}y + \cdots \end{align}$$ and see if something develops when you add the equations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If nine coins are tossed, what is the probability that the number of heads is even?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134991/if-nine-coins-are-tossed-what-is-the-probability-that-the-number-of-heads-is-ev)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a_N$ be the probability that $N$ Bernoulli trials result in an *even  number of successes*.
This occurs if an initial failure is followed by an even number of successes, or an initial success
is followed by an odd number of successes. Therefore $a_0=1$ and for $N\geq 1$
$$a_N=q a_{N-1}+p(1-a_{N-1}).$$
Multiplying by $s^N$ and adding over $N$ we see that the generating function
satisfies
$$H(s)=1+qsH(s)+ps(1-s)^{-1}-psH(s)$$
or
$$2H(s)=[1-s]^{-1}+[1-(q-p)s]^{-1}.$$
Expanding the right hand side using geometric series we find that the coefficients
satisfy $$a_N={1\over 2}+{(q-p)^N\over 2}.$$

**Reference**: Chapter XI of *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications (Volume 1)* (3rd edition) by William Feller.

Comment: Hoped it would be simpler, but thanks!

Comment: @Shmoopy Well the derivation is not that easy, but the final answer is quite nice.

Comment: A small note, $q$ is defined as $q=1-p$ (i.e. the probability of failure)

Comment: Is it possible to have a more specific reference in the book? I can't find where it talks about this.

Comment: What boggles me about it is how would you define the sample space in this problem to get the complement probability that is used in the solution. If $A_n$ is the event of having an even number of heads after n tosses, it is well defined in a sample space of n tosses. But then what is the event $A_{n-1}^c$ in the same sample space? It should include the event of odd number of heads after $n-1$ tosses, but also even number after n tosses, since it's in the complement. How would you define the sample space for both $A_n$ and $A_{n-1}$?

Comment: Somehow I don't really see how to get to the equation for 2H(s). Any hints?

Comment: nvm I got it after a coffee break. For other people wondering: You get there by first getting all the H(s) on one side, and then multiplying by two. Then write 2=1+1 and write (1-(q-p)s) =(1-s+2ps).