# Condition for probability of even number heads to be $1/2$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Suppose we flip $n$ coins (each flip is independent, but not necessarily identically distributed). Under what conditions will the probability that we flip an even number of heads be exactly $1/2$?

I know that when all the coins are fair, then the probability is half (see e.g. [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134991/if-nine-coins-are-tossed-what-is-the-probability-that-the-number-of-heads-is-ev)). But I'm not sure how to handle the case if the coins aren't fair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick a coin, suppose it comes up heads with probability $p$. Suppose the other $n-1$ coins give an even number of heads with probability $q$. Then we need
$$p(1-q)+(1-p)q=\frac{1}{2}\implies p+q-2pq=\frac{1}{2}\implies(2p-1)(2q-1)=0.$$
So either $p=\frac{1}{2}$ or $q=\frac{1}{2}$. Inducting downwards implies that the probability of an even number of heads is $\frac{1}{2}$ iff at least one of the coins is fair.

Answer (score 3):

I like jlammy's solution. Here's an alternative proof without induction.

Denote $p_i, q_i$ the probability of the $i^{th}$ coin getting a head or tail, respectively. Then $p_i+q_i=1$. Consider the following product:

$$T=(q_1-p_1) (q_2 -p_2) \cdots (q_n - p_n) = P-M \tag 1$$

where $P$ is the sum of all positive terms after expansion, and $M$ is the absolute value of the sum of all negative terms. Then $P$ is the probability of getting an even number of heads, $M$ is the probability of getting an odd number of heads, and $P+M=1$. Therefore,

$$P=M = \frac 12 \iff T=0  \iff p_i=q_i=\frac 12, \text{ for some }i. \blacksquare$$